# Pass Parameter through Callable - Jave, Android

Tags: java, android, parameter-passing, procedure, callable

I have managed to use Callable to pass my procedure to another class, the class then calls it once done. The class creates a HashMap of String and I want to be able to pass that to the callable procedure but I can't figure it out :S

```
passes the procedure to the class
stockDisplaying = new SQLStatements().LoadAllDrinks(this, new Callable<Integer>() {
            public Integer call() {
                return callWhenDone(null);
           }
        });

the procedure I'm passing I want to be able to send to HashMap to
public int callWhenDone(HashMap<String, String> map){
    Log.d("StockActivity", "omfg this works");
    return 0;
}

Where the class calls the procedure and should send the HashMap
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        try {
            callWhenDone.call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("LoadAllDrinks", "Exception" + e);
        }
}
```

Comment: You need another interface besides `Callable`.  You might need to make your own.

Comment: You mind telling what what I would do to create an interface, never done/ heard of that before